# Как отсортировать массив?

Tags: javascript

Допустим был массив

Данные:

```
['1','2','3','4']
```

Ключи порядка:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

Поместим '3' на 1 место.
Данные:

```
['3','1','2','4']
```

Старые ключи порядка:

```
[3,1,2,4]
```

Как можно отсортировать этот массив средствами javascript

```
['1','2','3','4']
```

Зная только ключи порядка и имея сам массив?

```
 var myArr =     ['1','2','3','4'];
 var orderList =  [3,1,2,4];
```

Comment: что-то непонятно из чего что надо получить

Comment: @АлексейШиманский переставить элементы `myArr` на позиции из `orderList` видимо

Comment: @manking,  Bам мои ответ подошел?

Comment: `2,3,1,4` результат нужен, или какой?

Comment: @teran видимо меня смутил массив 1,2,3,4 вместо какого-то разнообразного, что в итоге стало непонятно почему из 1234 надо сделать 3124 вместо того, чтоб просто его взять :D и что это еще назвали сортировкой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var myArr =     ['1','2','3','4'];
var orderList =  [3,1,2,4];
var ans=[];

orderList.forEach(function(child) {
 ans.push(myArr[child-1])
});
console.log(ans);
```

ans - отсортированный массив

Comment: Да, то что надо.

Comment: @manking, тогда почему бы не поставить галочку :)

Comment: @YernarSadybekov ну например потому что кто-то еще придет и даст еще круче ответ?

Comment: `ans = orderList.map(x => myArr[x - 1]);`

Comment: @manking, Может уже поставите галочку?

Comment: Сайт сразу не даёт поставить галочку. Это неудобно.